# Graphical Layout error in Eclipse IDE

Tags: android, graphical-layout-editor

There is this project I am making, and  I needed to copy an xml code from another project.
After I did so, none of the xml files in my project show up in the Graphical Layout.
Instead there is this warning written :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error Log
```

When I look it up in Error Log, I get.

Message:

```
chat_layout.xml: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Exception Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.graphics.Bitmap_Delegate.nativeWidth(Bitmap_Delegate.java:291)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeWidth(Bitmap.java)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth(Bitmap.java:909)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.getScaledWidth(Bitmap.java:957)
    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.computeBitmapSize(BitmapDrawable.java:179)
    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.setBitmap(BitmapDrawable.java:187)
    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.<init>(BitmapDrawable.java:555)
    at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.<init>(BitmapDrawable.java:110)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.ResourceHelper.getDrawable(ResourceHelper.java:239)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.loadIcon(CustomBar.java:196)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.loadIconById(CustomBar.java:188)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.CustomBar.loadIconById(CustomBar.java:155)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.FakeActionBar.<init>(FakeActionBar.java:38)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:333)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:332)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:325)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:440)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1545)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1302)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1059)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegatePageChange(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:683)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.common.CommonXmlEditor.pageChange(CommonXmlEditor.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart$2.widgetSelected(MultiPageEditorPart.java:290)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1077)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1062)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:774)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setSelection(CTabFolder.java:2746)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.onMouse(CTabFolder.java:1433)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder$1.handleEvent(CTabFolder.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3758)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2701)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2665)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2499)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:668)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

The Graphical Layout works fine for all other xml files for all of my projects in Eclipse, except this one. Everything worked fine before the the copy. What to do ??

The xml file is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_write_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textbox"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Write here"
            android:padding="5sp"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_margin="5sp"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"
            android:paddingBottom="5sp"
            android:paddingLeft="15sp"
            android:paddingRight="15sp"
            android:paddingTop="5sp"
            android:text="Send"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_write_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:listSelector="#00000000" >
    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_write_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please also provide the chat_layout.xml which causes the error. It looks like an image ressource is missing and prevent the UI to render...

Comment: Yes, i have attached the code as well now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems I was using an incompatible icon type for my app.
when I changed the Icon type it worked. It was a silly mistake but it kept me occupied :/

Answer (score 0):

Check if all your res images from sources are in bin/res folder

Comment: They are, but the problem was type incompatibility!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have either of the 2 issues.

1. Your file is named incorrectly, check your Problems tab
2. Restart your eclipse, graphical view sometimes take a lot of memory and messes up. If you run Juno, run a update, the latest one is a bit more stable.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this problem yesterday, I solved it just now. Just try to install lower or higher API level Platform SDK. At the beginning, I wished my application can work with old platform, so I created my program with old style theme, but when i edited my xml and view it with 4.3 SDK, i got this error.